# Cognito Forms says the entire Web Apps user base is actually part of Cognito's community

Tags: discussion, support, questions

Cognito Forms, with the wording on their [Support page](https://cognitoforms.com/support), have new users to Web Apps thinking that it's actually all part of Cognito.

> Have a question about Cognito Forms? Participate in questions & answers from our online community to learn more about Cognito Forms.
>
> #### View questions and answers.
>
> See what questions other users of Cognito Forms have asked.
>
> #### Ask a question.
>
> Our community is ready to answer. No registration is necessary.

It would be better for both sides if Cognito were told to update the copy pointing out that [cognito](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito) tagged questions are only a subset of what Web Apps answers.

And certainly aren't to be considered "their" community.

Comment: A vast majority of the questions posted about the product seem to be about self-hosted Wordpress installations handling the completed forms, rather than the use of the Cognito web interface to create forms.  To me, those types of questions are off-topic anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. We will take it under consideration to make it more clear that the user is leaving Cognito Apps.

Comment: Has anyone alerted Stack Exchange management? They generally like to know about these things and I've seen some specific guidance in the past.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project | http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19852/use-stack-overflow-as-the-official-support-site-of-an-open-source-project | http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195558/product-support-redirects-to-stack-overflow

Comment: Was using this post as the signal for SE to get around to it when it's doing the rounds @ale

Comment: Example of presumption: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/65864/revisions

Answer (score 5):

It was my decision to encourage Cognito Forms users to ask questions on Web Apps they could not answer via our help site.  I based this decision on our teams extensive use and love for Stack Exchange (especially Stack Overflow) along with our goal of transparency when assisting our users.

My intent was to model our support process after the setup then used by Trello, where we have a dedicated help site to answer most questions, and specific forms to submit feature requests and bug reports, while directly users to Stack Exchange to ask "how to" questions.  Sadly, Trello now uses Desk.com and there is not much visibility into the types of questions being asked or the answers.  For reference, [here is a thread](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/957/trello-is-making-its-users-think-were-a-bug-tracker-or-place-for-feature-reques) specifically discussing Trello's initial use of Stack Exchange and changes they made based on feedback from the Web Apps community.

However, in reviewing the specific wording on our support page, I see we failed to communicate our use of Stack Exchange Web Apps appropriately to our users.  We should have been clear that this was a completely separate site with no affiliation with Cognito Forms.  We will work to address this in our next release as we are already in the process of revamping our support page.

Additionally, we encourage users of WordPress to use the WordPress forums for questions about using our WordPress plugin.  While most users do this, we do have a number that miss this hint, so we will work to make this more obvious as well.  Unfortunately, we cannot select our users and for many this is their first exposure to the Stack Exchange family of websites.

We appreciate this feedback and would definitely like to hear specifics about how to encourage appropriate use of Stack Exchange Web Apps by our users!

Comment: Suggesting your users "might be able to find help on a welcoming Q&A site such as Web Apps Stack Exchange" with the current links should help ease or at least hopefully change how some address their issues (to whom) when posting a question.

Comment: We are releasing a major update to Cognito Forms next week, including a revamped support page directing users first to our comprehensive online help.  The support page has clear options to Request a Feature and Report a Bug, but also has links to Stack Exchange like the following: Forum - Join the conversation on Stack Exchange to [ask questions](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cognito&title=Cognito%20Forms:%20) and [view answers](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=cognito) about Cognito Forms.  We tried to be more explicit based on feedback.

Comment: @pnuts I have been getting mixed feedback from moderators on StackExchange,  We are in the process of revising how we present help content.  We will remove either remove the *Cognito Forms:* prefix during this update, or simply remove links to Stack Exchange.  We definitely do not want to cause strife!