# Site being used for Cognito Forms Customer Service

Tags: support

I have noticed these threads below are Customer Service requests for Cognito Forms:

- [Cognito Forms: Not working](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113625/cognito-forms-not-working)
- [Can you fix the Cognito forms ? They are not opening today?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113622/can-you-fix-the-cognito-forms-they-are-not-opening-today)
- [Cognitoforms not working today.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113614/cognitoforms-not-working-today)
- [All forms are not working](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113610/all-forms-are-not-working)
- [Cognito Forms: I can't access our data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113634/cognito-forms-i-cant-access-our-data)
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113636/cognito-forms-server-down-again

I have flagged as many as I can but I feel the need to raise it here because of the volume of posts and comments that these are attracting over the last few hours.

I would also like to point out that the [Cognito help](https://help.cognitoforms.com/) website has a link to these questions as per the picture below.

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A]

Can these please be deleted as we are **not** customer support.

Comment: FWIW, I'm guessing that the links back to SE are showing the most recent questions, not specifically intentionally those three.

Comment: @SurajRao, already on there, second one down :)

Comment: It'd be nice if one of those could be the canonical question and all the others closed as a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, we can't blame the users; they're just following the instructions on the help page. They don't know our rules; that this is a Q&A site and not a discussion forum. By the way, [this page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn't even list customer support questions as off-topic. That's probably why they post the same question multiple times, and 'me too'-non-answers. Coincidentally, [this user](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/113636/136642) even managed to accept the duplicate I suggested.

<sub>Note that it also could have been a possible troll; we had a similar situation in the past with [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109924/136642) where somebody posted a lot of anonymous (non-)answers (with separate names) stating that they had this problem too, in various ways.</sub>

Flagging the questions as off-topic is correct; it's harder to flag them as duplicates because that's only possible if the target has an upvoted answer. The ♦ moderators are already notified (via this meta-topic, and via chat) and will deal with the mess here; we're also reaching out to Cognito Forms to adjust the widget on their help page.

In the meantime, the flood of posts has dried, so the service is probably working again.

Comment: I noticed that their login page is slow and sometimes timing out at the moment, so at least on this it occasion it seems like there's something wrong with their server.

Answer (score 0):

As already [was mentioned](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4500/88163), the correct way to proceed is to flag/vote to close as off-topic, first. Those questions eventually could be deleted.

I think that we could benefit from having as FAQ a question like

[Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)

A link to the above post could be included in the closing reason so the OPs could have a bit of an extended explanation about why their questions were put on hold / closed.

As of April 2023 in [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com), there are +100 posts that have been bumped by Community-User more than +20 times. Most of these posts are +5 years old. From the Top 100, 57 are tagged [cognito-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognito-forms). For details see [answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5016/88163) to [Kind reminder, voting is Important!](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4889/88163)

---

From [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) (emphasis mine)

> **Questions can also be deleted by the community**. Moderators can delete any question, and users with sufficient reputation can cast delete votes **on closed questions**. It takes 3 votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However, the number of delete-votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers. Questions that have been closed within the past 48 hours cannot be deleted, to allow for editing and possible reopening.

## Related

- [Cognito Forms says the entire Web Apps user base is actually part of Cognito's community](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2674/88163)