# Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]

Tags: support, faq, close-reasons

Why can't I ask customer service-related questions here, like:

- The service is down. Fixed it!
- When will [some new feature] be released?

Can I ask questions about using their app?  How is that different?

Comment: See https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4504/88163

Comment: Note: Content based on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/1595451

Comment: [In the context of webapps, how can one assess whether a question is a customer service-related question?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5203/18147)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?

Because we don't know the answer.

Oh sure, there might be some intrepid soul who has sailed these waters before, and come out alive.  They might even be able to offer some insight.  There might even be the occasional employee wandering these hallowed halls.  But here's the problem:

**We're not Google, Facebook, Microsoft, or Apple Customer Service.**

We don't set policy for these companies.  We don't have telephone lines, confirmation code generators, or any authority to make decisions on your behalf.  We don't track changes to policy, except by anecdote and hearsay, so any answer we give you today is going to be wrong tomorrow, if it isn't already wrong.

Here's the other problem:

**We're not here to act as customer support on any company's behalf.**

That's not our mission.  We're here to help you with your challenges using a web app.  If that web app includes a coding feature (macro, script, custom JavaScript/HTML/CSS, fine.  We're more than happy to help you with that.  But we don't know if the service outage will be restored soon.  We can't give you a confirmation code either solve pay issues.  We don't know how long it will take them to release that shiny new thing.

We just don't know.  All we can do is refer you to customer support.

### But I was referred here by [company] for support!

Yes.  For your on-topic, how-to questions.  For your questions having specifically to do with using a web application.  But for questions that involve customer service issues, you need to contact the company directly.

If the referring company did not give you clear guidance as to what types of questions would be a good fit for Web Applications, [contact the community team](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/contact) and let them know; they might be able to reach out to the company and help them establish better guidance to avoid confusion for everyone.

**Further Reading**

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [What kind of questions can I ask here? The detailed version](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/894/)
- [Can I support my product on this site?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/product-support)
- [On which Stack Exchange site can I ask customer service questions about product X or company Y?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347991/289691)

Comment: Content based on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/1595451

Comment: I recommend care when using this close reason. Except when "the website if fully and obviously down", It can be very hard to know if something is publicly documented or not, or if it is an internal implementation detail. A large part of the point of asking here is to find out if there is some public documentation on the feature or not.

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com I'm sorry for the long delay on replying. Do you remember a question closed with this reason that bring you to leave this comment?

Comment: Hi, this was the one: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/149933/why-does-the-archive-org-of-most-youtube-videos-fail-with-sorry-the-wayback-mac The reason many links fail is likely intentional undocumented behaviour/bad UI of the website, likely not a one off occurrence. One they they might document that officially/we might find a documentation for it.

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com Thanks for your reply. I will review this carefully tonight.

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com I have reviewed the question and effectively it's is not a got fit for this site. P.S. I don't think that Wayback Machive "Save page" button is able to archive Youtube videos.

Comment: OK, thanks. It does work for some videos for sure BTW, I have seen it before. There has since been a thread: https://archive.org/post/1102732/many-youtube-videos-which-used-to-work-on-the-wayback-machine-dont-work-anymore maybe they all stopped working. If the question were allowed, such clarifications would be useful to Googlers. But OK.

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com I suggest you to create a new meta post or a new question. These comments will be purged in few days.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not use time for this. I do seriously appreciate that you had a second look into it, many thanks for that. All best.