# What flag should be used for customer service questions?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, flagging

I have just seen [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114503/how-can-i-reback-my-gmail-account-from-someone-else-has-hacked-my-account) question which looks to me immediately off topic because it is a customer service question, which is off-topic according to [this](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

But when I look at the off-topic flag list:[image: Flag List]
I am unable to see a flag that would fit this type of questions.

**My Suggestion:**
What about a specific flag for customer service/support questions so that it makes it clearer to users when the closed message comes up. It could read something like this:

> As we are not here to act on behalf of any company, we are unable to answer customer service requests. It would be best to contact the company directly in this situation. For more information see [this](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) meta post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're still just flagging, and not actually voting to close, I suggest using the "blatantly off-topic" flag.

Once you get the privilege to vote to close, you should use a custom reason.