# Is it OK to ask about rules of web applications?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Is it appropriate to ask about **usage rules** of web applications? For example "I posted the lyrics of a song as a comment to that song on YouTube and my account got locked without reference to which YouTube rules I violated. Which rules might I have violated?"

According to the [on-topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [dont-ask](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) pages, that question seems to fit the allowed category "Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application", and none of the forbidden categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A question like

> I posted the lyrics of a song as a comment to that song on YouTube and my account got locked without reference to which YouTube rules I violated. Which rules might I have violated?

Looks to be a primarily-opinion based, specially because there isn't a reference to which YouTube rules were violated and doesn't include the account activity history.

Questions like that should be asked on the YouTube help forum because a Google Product Expert might give their opinion (that is "someway" endorsed by Google) regarding how the account blocking is working at that moment, etc.

Google Product Experts have bronce, silver, gold, platinum or diamond badges awarded by Google. To learn more about this program go to https://productexperts.withgoogle.com/

Disclaimer: I'm a Google Product Expert (formerly a Google Top Contributor) for several products but not for Youtube.

Related

- [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)