# Is it OK to seed Questions and Answers?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I just came across [this](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/936/steel-your-resolve-trello-is-upon-us-and-we-are-flooded) meta post, and the consensus seemed to be that it's ok to seed questions from genuine users about a web-app, and answer them on webapps.stackexchange.

Is this (still) the case?

I'd like to add a couple of questions and answers that I think would help people searching for answers about Coggle, but want to check if it's OK first.

Comment: How about offering a sample question/answer you'd be posting?

Comment: @AlEverett After thinking through a few examples, I think the questions I'd answer all have answers on our site anyway... I guess the sort of questions that fit well here are things that aren't answered elsewhere because they're neat tricks/ways of doing things, rather than simple questions along the lines of "how do I X"

Answer (score 2):

If you had a problem with a Web Application that you solved and you think that it would benefit other users then please do post the question and answer.

You can even post the answer at the same time as the question.

However, if this is *your* web application then you are potentially skating on thin ice/sailing close to the wind (pick your metaphor) as regard to the self publicity/astro turfing rule.

We would much rather questions came from your users and you answered (clearing stating that you ran the site).

If you already have frequently asked questions then you'd probably be better addressing these actually on your site.

Comment: I'm actually one of the creators of the web-app in question, and I answer a lot of support questions, so it would be *other people's* questions's I'd be posting.

Comment: @James - Ah. That does put a different spin on things.